# TF14044: Access Denied: User Mustapha EL ALAMI needs the AdminWorkspaces global permission(s)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

TF14044: Access Denied: User Mustapha EL ALAMI needs the AdminWorkspaces global permission(s).
But I have all permissions!

Comment: Boo to anyone to -1 this question. Somebody had a problem and reached out. That's what StackExchange is supposed to be for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check the permissions for the user, make sure the permission "`Administer Workspaces`" and "`Create a workspace`" are set to **Allow**:

For on-premise TFS, navigate to `http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_security` and select the specific user/group to set the permission.

For Azure DevOps, navigate to `https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_security`, filter your user account (enter your user name in `Filter users and groups`) , check you permission settings.

[image]

Comment: same problem :/

Comment: my freinds have the same permissions  they work good 
but me i m denied !!

Comment: Please filter your user (enter your user name in `Filter users and groups`) and check the permission again, note that it's in collection level. If that still not work, please capture and share the screenshot for troubleshoot here.

Comment: @MuStaphaElAlami Please note that `it's in collection level`, not project level. You can see that your screenshot is different with the one I provided in above answer. Please navigate to `http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_security` to check and set the permission.

Comment: like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD7yE.png,,
this link "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_security" not work for me

Comment: @MuStaphaElAlami You are using Azure DevOps (VSTS) but not on-premise TFS. OK, Please navigate to `https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_security`, filter your user account (enter your user name in `Filter users and groups`) , check you permission settings.

Comment: But all friends have the same, this an example https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRp8H.png

Comment: the probleme is the administrateur is out , to allow "Administer Workspaces" and "Create a workspace"
but he give me the same permission

Comment: @MuStaphaElAlami So you need to check the permissions of all the groups which your user account added in, in TFS/VSTS the `deny` always win unless you set the permission explicitly just as you did here...

Comment: what the probleme i don t now :/ :/ :/

Comment: but your answer will work for another thank you Andy

Comment: Andy it work hahaahh i call the administrator to allow "Administer Workspaces" , finalyy it woooork thank youu so much